# Перенос строки через JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Пишу небольшой чат. Каждое новое сообщение нужно выводить с новой строки.

Написал вот так:

```
document.getElementById("chat").textContent = document.getElementById("chat").textContent + "</br>" + newMsg;
```

То есть, старался опираться на  который в html переносит строку, но здесь, в моем случае  воспринимается как обыкновенный текст. Как переносить каждое новое сообщение на новую строку?

Comment: делайте по блоку на сообщение

Comment: Как создать блок через JS подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: В каком html элементе делаете? Быть может, он выводит все, как чистый текст? Тогда \r\n вместо <br> поможет.

Comment: Если чат находится в <div id="chat"></div>


<script>$("#chat").append("<div class='msg'>"+newMsg+"</div>");</script>

Comment: Все будет работать, если вы будете использовать innerHtml )

Comment: в том числе и эксплойты со вставкой кода

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По поводу Вашего вопроса - вы устанавливаете `textContent`  тег `<br>` в нем не сработает.

Я бы Вам советовал добавлять каждое сообщение отдельным элементом, так проще сделать оформление или анимацию для сообщений, если это конечно требуется

```js
let chat = document.getElementById("chat");

setInterval(e => {
  addMessage(Math.random().toString(36).substring(2));
  chat.childNodes.length >= 5 && removeFirstMessage();
}, 1000)

function addMessage(newMsg) {
  let block = document.createElement('div');
  block.classList.add('block');
  block.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random()*360},55%,85%)`;
  block.textContent = newMsg;
  setTimeout(e => block.style.opacity = 1);
  chat.append(block);
}

function removeFirstMessage() {
  chat.firstChild.style.opacity = 0;
  let h = chat.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  chat.firstChild.style.marginTop = `-${h + 5}px`; // 5 - margin
  setTimeout(e => chat.firstChild.remove(), 500);
}
```

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat"></div>
```

Comment: Это невероятно круто! Спасибо огромное, чат действительно красивый! К сожалению я новичок и практически не понял половны, но буду учить. Еще раз, спасибо!

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда задавайте вопросы, по непонятным местам, тут все достаточно не сложно

Comment: chat.childNodes.length >= 5 && removeFirstMessage(); здесь не совсем понятно, если бы это было условием - понял бы смысл, а здесь для меня он немного теряется под "&&"

Comment: можно сказать что это if (...),основано это на порядке вычисления булевых операторов, если то что идет до && уже false, то то что идет после && уже не проверяется, т.к. нет смысла

Comment: Спасибо, а вот это что, если не трудно?  setTimeout(e => block.style.opacity = 1);
  chat.append(block);

Comment: `setTimeout(e => block.style.opacity = 1)` setTimeout откладывает выполнение переданной туда функции, здесь это затем, чтобы браузер анимировал значение прозрачности, а не просто его установил без анимации

Comment: `chat.append(block); ` непосредственно функция добавления узла

Comment: Понял. Подскажите пожалуйста, здесь все  правильно если без анимации? let block = document.createElement('div');
  block.classList.add('block');
  block.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${Math.random()*360},55%,85%)`;
  block.textContent = msg.data;
  chat.append(block);

Comment: можно еще цвет убрать `block.style.backgroundColor = hsl(${Math.random()*360},55%,85%)`

Comment: Спасибо большое, можно еще последний вопрос? Что вот это такое let h = chat.firstChild.getBoundingClientRect().height;

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: Удачи Вам) и всего наилучшего)

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда спасибо и Вам успехов, обращайтесь